# How does flow_from_directory implemented?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My main question is, does it iterate over every sample in the directory for every epoch? I have directory with 6 classes with almost same number of samples in each class, when I trained model with `batch_size=16` it didn't work at all, predicts only 1 class correctly. Making `batch_size=128` made that, it can predict 3 classes with high accuracy and other 3 never appeared in test predictions. Why it did so? Does every `steps_per_epoch` uniquely generated and it only remembers samples of that batch? Which means that it does not remember last used batch samples and creates new random batch with possibility to use already used samples and miss others, if so then it means that it misses whole class samples and the only way to overcome this would be increasing `batch_size` so that it will remember it in one batch. I can't increase `batch_size` more than 128 because there is not enough memory on my GPU. 

So what should I do?

Here is my code for `ImageDataGenerator`

```py
train_d = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.1, validation_split=0.2,
                             rotation_range=10.,
                             width_shift_range=0.1,
                             height_shift_range=0.1)
train_s = train_d.flow_from_directory('./images/', target_size=(width, height),
                                      class_mode='categorical',
                                      batch_size=32, subset='training')

validation_s = train_d.flow_from_directory('./images/', target_size=(width, height), class_mode='categorical',
                                           subset='validation')
```

And here is code for `fit_generator`

```py
classifier.fit_generator(train_s, epochs=20, steps_per_epoch=100, validation_data=validation_s,
                                   validation_steps=20, class_weight=class_weights)
```

Comment: Yes, it iterates for every sample in each folder every epoch.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro so if I set `batch_size` to 1 and `steps_per_epoch` to 1, it will iterate over whole directory? I am pretty sure it won't.

Comment: No, steps per epoch should be set to len(dataset) / batch_size

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro well, then that answers my question, Thanks! If you want you can post answer and I will mark it. BTW what will it do if `steps_per_epoch` is more than len(dataset)/batch_size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it iterates for every sample in each folder every epoch. This is the definition of en epoch, a complete pass over the whole dataset.

`steps_per_epoch` should be set to `len(dataset) / batch_size`, then only issue is when the batch size does not exactly divide the number samples, and in that case you round `steps_per_epoch` up and the last batch is smaller than `batch_size`.