# How to correctly use ImageDataGenerator in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am playing with augmentation of data in Keras lately and I am using basic ImageDataGenerator. I learned the hard way it is actually a generator, not iterator (because `type(train_aug_ds)` gives `<class 'keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>` I thought it is an iterator). I also checked few blogs about using it, but they don't answer all my questions.

So, I loaded my data like this:

```
train_aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    brightness_range=(0.5,1.5),
    zoom_range = [1, 1.5],
)
train_aug_ds = train_aug.flow_from_directory(
    directory='./train',
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

And to train my model I did the following:

```
model.fit(
    train_aug_ds,
    epochs=150,
    validation_data=(valid_aug_ds,),
)
```

And it worked. I am a bit confused how it works, because `train_aug_ds` is generator, so it should give infinitely big dataset. And documentation says:

> When passing an infinitely repeating dataset, you must specify the steps_per_epoch argument.

Which I didn't do, yet, it works. Does it somehow infer number of steps? Also, does it use only augmented data, or it also uses non-augmented images in batch?

So basically, my question is how to use this generator correctly with function `fit` to have all data in my training set, including original, non-augmented images and augmented images, and to cycle through it several times/steps (right now it seems it does only one step per epoch)?

Comment: Answer is great, thank you very much. I am sorry, I wasn't online for a few days. I accepted it as answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the documentation can be quite confusing and I imagine the behavior is different depending on your Tensorflow and Keras version. For example, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048848/model-works-fine-in-keras-but-not-in-tensorflow), the user is describing the exact behavior you are expecting. Generally, the `flow_from_directory()` method allows you to read the images directly from a directory and augment them while your model is being trained and as already stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134404/how-does-flow-from-directory-implemented), it iterates for every sample in each folder every epoch. Using the following example, you can check that this is the case (on TF 2.7) by looking at the steps per epoch in the progress bar:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 64

flowers = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)

img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
)

train_ds = img_gen.flow_from_directory(flowers, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, class_mode='sparse')
num_classes = 5

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))

epochs=10
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

```
Found 3670 images belonging to 5 classes.
Epoch 1/10
 6/58 [==>...........................] - ETA: 3:02 - loss: 2.0608
```

If you wrap `flow_from_directory` with `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` like this:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: img_gen.flow_from_directory(flowers, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, class_mode='sparse'),
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32))
```

You will notice that the progress bar looks like this because `steps_per_epoch` has not been explicitly defined:

```
Epoch 1/10
Found 3670 images belonging to 5 classes.
     29/Unknown - 104s 4s/step - loss: 2.0364
```

And if you add this parameter, you will see the steps in the progress bar:

```
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  steps_per_epoch = len(from_directory),
  epochs=epochs
)
```

```
Found 3670 images belonging to 5 classes.
Epoch 1/10
 3/58 [>.............................] - ETA: 3:19 - loss: 4.1357
```

Finally, to your question:

> How to use this generator correctly with function fit to have all
> data in my training set, including original, non-augmented images and
> augmented images, and to cycle through it several times/step?

You can simply increase the `steps_per_epoch` beyond `number of samples // batch_size` by multiplying by some factor:

```
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  steps_per_epoch = len(from_directory)*2,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

```
Found 3670 images belonging to 5 classes.
Epoch 1/10
  1/116 [..............................] - ETA: 12:11 - loss: 1.5885
```

Now instead of 58 steps per epoch you have 116.

Comment: `it iterates for every sample in each folder every epoch`. This is very helpful. TensorFlow's document is very ambiguous about what the generator returns exactly.